# Emulator -avd does not launch the virtual device

Tags: emulation, android-emulator

on Ubuntu 16.04 I have installed AndroidStudio and via its AVD manager GUI did create tow new devices. now on Terminal when I type `emulator -list-avds` it lists the devices correctly, but when run `emulator -avd <name>` I face errors:

```
[139684796983104]:ERROR:android/android-emu/android/qt/qt_setup.cpp:28:Qt library not found at ../emulator/lib64/qt/lib
Could not launch '/home/amir/../emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-i386': No such file or directory
```

How should I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can solve this by calling the emulator from the directory where it is installed: e.g.

```
$ cd /home/amir/Android/Sdk/tools/
$ emulator -avd <name>
```

Consider creating an env variable `$ANDROID_HOME`.

If your directory matches my example above, set the variable to `/home/amir/Android/Sdk` (don't include tools).

Some people report that this resolved the problem for them, so that they didn't even need to start the emulator from within the tools directory.

I cannot confirm this though, but it's easier to `cd $ANDROID_HOME/tools && emulator <name>`, isn't it?

Comment: Ok. Got it. First try to launch it from within your Android/Sdk/tools directory. If this works, add `$ANDROID_HOME/emulator` to your PATH (e.g. `vim ~/.bashrc` or `vim ~/.zshrc` or whatever is appropriate for you). Open a new terminal and then you can launch emulator from everywhere. Note however: it is important that the emulator directory is placed **before** the tools directory.

Comment: Thanks, man, it worked its weird. but I get this error do you anything about this too :   emulator: ERROR: Missing initial data partition file: /home/amir/.android/avd/nexus4.avd/userdata.img

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47895124/emulator-emulator-error-missing-initial-data-partition-file – seems to be a one time error that goes away after first start. Correct?

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu 19.10!

With the environment variables already configured ($ANDROID_HOME), you should be able to list the AVDs, but if you are unable to start the AVD, do the following:

# Check the AVD target name

> emulator -list-avds

# But to start do:

> $ANDROID_HOME/emulator/emulator @avd_name

or

> /home/$USER/Android/Sdk/emulator/emulator @avd_name

Comment: had the same problem in macos and this worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Had this error recently on Arch Linux. Simplest resolution for me was to add an alias to `~/.profile` like this:
`alias emulator='cd /home/myusername/Android/Sdk/tools ; emulator`

Then you can just use it normally, i.e. `emulator -avd <name>` without having to worry about switching directories beforehand.